# Zoom gallery view with their Video SDK

Tags: zoom-sdk

I am evaluating the suitability of the Zoom Video SDK (Web) for a new application, but I have concerns about participant count limitations and rendering a gallery view.

### Hard upper limit

I could not find a definitive upper limit to how many participants can join a session. Does anyone know of a hard limit?

### Viewing participants

There are notes about viewing all these participants, for example [the official guide](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/web/essential/video) says

> the SDK can only render 9 videos at the same time

I assume this means that one can render a paged gallery view with up to 9 participants per page. Is this correct?

Or is there a different way to stream a bigger item count per page where, say the gallery is stitched together on Zoom's servers and streamed as one video to the session client?

### Example code

In April [Gallery view was announced](https://8xmdmkir8ctlkfj8dttx.noticeable.news/publications/web-sdk-updates-04-19-21), but I could not find any example code. Can anyone point me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. This means that the Zoom web clients (Whether the Zoom Web Client, Zoom Video SDK [AKA: 'fully customizable'], or Zoom Meetings SDK) are only capable of rendering 9 participants at a time. It is not possible to 'stitch together' larger views on a server. This is a client limitation.

You should also be aware of video quality. All Zoom web clients are currently (Aug 2021) limited to 360P. (See "Performance Limits" https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web)
This means that published video is sent at significantly degraded resolution relative to their applications or native SDKs. This applies to video sent from and received by the client.

If you are considering a web-first (not installed application) video solution, there are many vendors who use WebRTC to achieve something like Google Meet and can run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What's the ideal number of videos you'd like displayed at one time? I agree with the suggestion above from Daniel O'Rorke-- if you're looking to have more than 9 videos in a gallery view at one time, you may prefer a WebRTC-based third-party video API solution. You can go into dozens (or more) for videos displayed at once.